# Extreme lag when showing notification

Tags: java, android, performance, android-service, android-notifications

### Original Question:

This is my first attempt at implementing a service and a notification, so please bear with me if the concept of my implementation is totally wrong.

---

### **Problem:**

I implemented a service that repeatedly shows a notification in a given interval. **Whenever the notification is shown, the notification is correctly displayed, but my phone starts to lag really bad.** It is not only my application that is lagging, it really is the whole phone, a Nexus 5X running Android 6.0.1. It almost gets unusable.

---

### **Implementation:**

**MainActivity** that starts the service:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

**MyService** that shows the notification

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private static long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1 * 10 * 1000;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    startService();
}

private void startService() {
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(

            new TimerTask() {

                public void run() {
                    refreshData();
                }
            }, 1000, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
}

private void refreshData() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("New notification")
            .setContentText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.home)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(1337, noti);
}

private void stopService() {
    if (mTimer != null) mTimer.cancel();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopService();
}
```

I can't really identify the part that is causing the lag, so any help is highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

---

### UPDATE:

The error was caused by a silly mistake of mine due to a way too large image file that was being loaded for the notifications (see accepted answer). I will still keep the question online since it pretty much demonstrates a full example on how to implement a service that displays notifications. (As long as the image file isn't too large :-) )

Comment: Does it happen immediately when starting to show the notification, or is it getting increasingly worse over time? Does it get better if you update less frequently (say, every 10 seconds instead)?

Comment: It starts lagging as soon as it displayed in the taskbar. The interval does not seem to be related since when I remove the notification from the taskbar the lag stops and starts again as soon as the next notification is shown.

Comment: Please try a *much* longer interval (or just not updating it at all). It'll give us a clue whether the time is spent continuously (example: drawing) or on some kind of initialization (example: image loading). And speaking of image loading, what does your R.drawable.home bitmap look like? How big is it?

Comment: Oh well,... I just found out that the file home.png was a 2000x2000 file. Changed it to an appropiate smaller file and it works like a charm. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yeah that would do it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so in the question comments, we found that the image used for the notification was 2000x2000 pixels. Changing it to a more reasonably sized image fixed the problem.

My assumption that the CPU usage comes from SystemUI (which displays the notifications) having the re-load that image *every time* the notification is updated. Decoding a 2000x2000 pixel png image will actually take a couple of hundred milliseconds.